# Convert matrix of lists to data.frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I've got this structure `tbl` that has the form:

```
> tbl

     a_1   a_2  a_3
 [1,] "L"  "14" "L"
 [2,] "L"  "62" "D"
 [3,] "H"  "0"  "L"
```

this is a matrix, actually:

```
> class(tbl)
[1] "matrix"
```

but when I attempt to change this into a `data.frame`, all the entries of the df are displaying only the datatype, like so:

```
>as.data.frame(tbl, nrow = length(tbl[,1]), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

a_1           a_2         a_3
<list>       <list>      <list>
<chr[1]>    <chr[1]>    <chr[1]>
<chr[1]>    <chr[1]>    <chr[1]>
<chr[1]>    <chr[1]>    <chr[1]>
```

I have tried a number of options but none of them seem to work including:

`data.frame(rows=rownames(tbl)[row(tbl)],vars=colnames(tbl)[col(tbl)], values=c(tbl))`

but I receive an error when I try to use it.  I would like the resulting `data.frame` to take the form:

```
a_1           a_2         a_3
<char>       <chr>      <char>
"L"           "14"        "L"
"L"           "62"        "D"
"H"           "0"         "L"
```

I looked for similar q's but couldn't find anyone who had this same issue. Any advice would be a great help!

---

```
dput(tbl)

structure(list("L", "L", "H", "14", "62", "0", "L", "D", "L"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a_1", "a_2", "a_3")))


str(tbl)

List of 9
 $ : chr "L"
 $ : chr "L"
 $ : chr "H"
 $ : chr "14"
 $ : chr "62"
 $ : chr "0"
 $ : chr "L"
 $ : chr "D"
 $ : chr "L"
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 3 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a_1" "a_2" "a_3"
```

Comment: Could you please provide your data using `dput` so that we can see exactly what data structure you have?

Comment: This is a smaller version of the original - I made an error on the datatype of column `a2` that I've now repaired.  Does it make sense now?

Comment: Ok, I broke it down a bit and this is the result: `structure(list("L", "L", "H", "14", "62", "0", "L", "D", "L"), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a_1", "a_2", "a_3")))`

Comment: `class` is sometimes not informative, run `str(tbl)` and add output to get a better sense of your data structure

Comment: result of `str(tbl)`: `List of 9
 $ : chr "L"
 $ : chr "L"
 $ : chr "H"
 $ : chr "14"
 $ : chr "62"
 $ : chr "0"
 $ : chr "L"
 $ : chr "D"
 $ : chr "L"
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 3 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a_1" "a_2" "a_3"`

Comment: Are you using `as.data.frame` or `as_data_frame`?

Comment: I tried both but I suspect I'm messing up some type of data-type because I couldn't get it to run without errors.  I am still very new at this and the structures of the data in R confuse me a bit.  I'm open to any method that gets this into a df.

Comment: `as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(tbl), nrow = nrow(tbl)))` provides what I'm looking for but the column names have dropped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one-liner:

```
as.data.frame(apply(tbl, 2, unlist))
```

or this:

```
tbl2 <- unlist(tbl)
attributes(tbl2) <- attributes(tbl)
DF <- as.data.frame(tbl2)
```

Comment: _yes!_ - I've been spinning my wheels for too long on this! Both options worked well.  I'll need to look into `apply` and `attributes` - both of these are new to me.  Thank you so much!!!